# Bootstrap: Make glyphicon within input clickable

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code that produces this: [image]

```
 <div class='input-group manualInput'>
       <input id='address-input' type='text'  class='form-control' placeholder='Enter your current location!'/>
       <span class='input-group-addon'>
          <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></i>
       </span>
  </div>
```

How do I make the glyphicon clickable? And call a JS function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a JavaScript `onClick` event like this:

```
<span class='input-group-addon'>
    <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search' onclick="myfunction();"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off their website:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Comment: Instead of down-voting my answer that someone else up-voted at the time, why don't you try editing my answer to fix it? This answer was from four years ago anyway, I'm sure Bootstrap has changed since then.